# REact dropdown click outside working but button inside menu not clickable

Tags: reactjs

I have this case where I made button when click outside to be closed, but now even the button inside menu it is not clickable

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


export const someething = () => {
 const [choose, setChoose] = useState(true)
  const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", toggleChoose);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", toggleChoose);
  };
  }, []);
  
   const toggleChoose = (e) => {
   if ( refContainer.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setChoose(true)
      return
   }
    setChoose(false)
  }


  const toggleSchedule = () => {
    setSchedule(!schedule)
    setChoose(!choose)
  }
  
  
    return <div className={styles.container}>
  
    <button  onClick={(e) => toggleChoose(!choose)}>
        <span >Choose </span>
      </button>
      
      
          {!choose &&
      <div className={styles.containerInside}>
      Other button to be clickable
        </div>
      </div>
    }
    
    </div>
    
    }
```

How can I make it when  menu is opened, the button " Other button to be clickable" to be clickable

Comment: can you post a sandbox with working code?